# PostgreSQL: hide table INSERT UPDATE DELETE behind a function

Tags: postgresql, permissions, database-schema, plpgsql, database-permissions

I understand how to use `GRANT` to control who can do what to a DB object.

I have a case where it would be useful to have specific functions that modify a table's contents while preventing a user from directly accessing the table.

Let's say I have a stock control table and I want a function `increase_stock(int)` that modifies only one column. There would be other functions that modify other columns, too.

My actual table has arrays of ltrees and arrays of ints, making a trigger an undesirable option as that does not present a clean way of directly manipulating only one field without testing for changes on each. More importantly, it doesn't create the APIs I desire.

Regardless of the approach, can I create a function that is visible to a user while that function accesses a table that is NOT visible to that user?

I'm using PG 10.

Comment: yes - if you use function as security defined

Comment: Thanks much! Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: no worries, did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example with select. more or less same would be for insert.update and delete:

```
t=# create table sd(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into sd select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# create user nr;
CREATE ROLE
t=# create function s() returns table (i int) as $$ 
begin
return query select * from sd;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

now login as nr:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -U nr t
psql (9.3.14)
Type "help" for help.

t=> select * from sd;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation sd
t=> select * from s();
 i
---
 1
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

> SECURITY INVOKER indicates that the function is to be executed with
>   the privileges of the user that calls it. That is the default.
>   SECURITY DEFINER specifies that the function is to be executed with
>   the privileges of the user that owns it.

Of course it means that function owner needs permissions on relation